# how to find all class name in ul > li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to change my html code by javascript. 
I want to add span tag for a tag if it contains has-children in class for li tag

`<span> <a></a> <span class="sub-menu-toggle"></span></span>`

it is my code that I can change first step li.has-children 
how can I change all ? class=has-children

```js
$('.has-children').each(function(i, e) {
  var aTag = $(this).find('a')[0].outerHTML;
  var ulTag = $(this).find('ul')[0].outerHTML;
  $(this).html('<span>' + aTag + '<span class="sub-menu-toggle"></span></span>' + ulTag);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="site-menu">
  <ul style="display: none">
    <li class="has-children">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">First Sub Menu</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)">Second Sub Menu</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

1. Use a better selector
2. wrap
3. after

```js
$('.has-children>a').each(function() {
  $(this).wrap('<span/>')
    .after('<span class="sub-menu-toggle"/>');
});
```

```css
a { text-decoration: none }
span a { text-decoration: underline }
.sub-menu-toggle::after { content: " ʘ" }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="site-menu">
  <ul style="display">
    <li class="has-children">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="has-children">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">First Sub Menu</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)">Second Sub Menu</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```